# Como converter uma string com minutos/mes/ano em TimeStamp?

Tags: java, string, timestamp

Estou fazendo um código para testes somente. Nele, tenho a seguinte `String`:

```
String tempo = "1s"; //1 segundo
```

Essa string é modificada o tempo todo:

```
String tempo = "30d"; //30 dias
```

Então, eu quero converter essa *string* que pode ser `s(segundo)/m(minuto)/d(dias)` em uma *timestamp* a partir do tempo atual. Quero usar o tempo atual mais o tempo q está na *string*. Como fazer?

```
String tempo = Métodos.getStringTempo();
int tempoSemLetra = Integer.valueOf(tempo.replace("m", "").replace("s", "").replace("d", ""));
long added = 0L;
if (tempo.endsWith("m")) {
   added = (tempoSemLetra*60)*1000; 
} else if (tempo.endsWith("s")) {
   added = (tempoSemLetra)*1000; 
else if (tempo.endsWith("d")) { 
   //Como converto os dias? 
}
```

Comment: Se tiver a quantidade de segundos é fácil, mas tendo que fazer *parsing* da *string*, ver se está tudo ok, já complica um pouco e provavelmente é ampla demais para responder. Sei que alguém vai cair na tentação de fazer uma análise superficial que funciona só se tudo estiver perfeito, mas que quebra se algo vier fora do padrão.

Comment: Tudo esta seguindo este padrão

Comment: E qual o padrao?

Comment: Não sei nem se tem tudo o que é necessário. É comum os requisitos nem estarem certos, precisa ter indicação clara, completa e não ambígua do que deseja. Pra falar a verdade nem sei se deve fazer isto, já que você está querendo converter um período de tempo em um ponto no tempo (*timestamp*), que são conceitos que parecem ser iguais, mas muito diferentes, então essa conversão nem faz sentido, a não ser que consiga justificar isso, o que duvido. De qualquer forma seria bom colocar o que já fez pra gente ver onde está sua dificuldade.

Comment: @DaviDEV edite a pergunta e adicione nela. O campo de comentários não é ideal para códigos.

Comment: Esse código não é suficiente para entender seu problema a não ser que apenas não saiba achar o tempo do dia. Mesmo que ainda tudo estivesse claro, como e porque pretende converter um período de tempo em um ponto no tempo? Entende esses conceitos? Entende que está querendo fazer uma laranja virar uma maça?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String tempo = Métodos.getStringTempo();
int tempoSemLetra = Integer.valueOf(tempo.replace("s", "").replace("m", "")
                                         .replace("h", "").replace("d", ""));
long added = 0L; //não sei porque precisa de long
if (tempo.endsWith("s")) {
   added = tempoSemLetra * 1000; 
} else if (tempo.endsWith("m")) {
   added = tempoSemLetra * 60 * 1000; 
} else if (tempo.endsWith("m")) {
   added = tempoSemLetra * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
else if (tempo.endsWith("d")) { 
   added = tempoSemLetra * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
}
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + added);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/ConvertToTimestamp.java).

Você não converte um período de tempo em um ponto no tempo, o que faz é pegar um ponto no tempo (o *timestamp*)  atual e somar uma quantidade de milésimos de acordo com o padrão da *string* apresentada. Esse é o conceito correto.

Adicionei hora também, não está na pergunta, mas não faz sentido não ter. Se não é para ter, é só tirar essa parte. Se tiver outras unidades, como mês e ano dá fazer. Não o fiz, porque está no título, mas não está no corpo da pergunta. Teria que ver qual será a letra usada para mês para não conflitar com minuto. E decidir qual será o tempo adotado, porque depende de cada mês. Para ano tem a complicação do ano bissexto.

Ressalto que isto é uma implementação ingênua e tudo tem que estar correto para funcionar. É possível que tenha outros requisitos, mas a pergunta não deixa claro nada sobre isto.

Por não ter um contexto maior do problema não posso falar muito, mas me parece pode existir solução melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
utilizando JodaTime, você consegue fazendo mais ou menos assim.

```
public class TesteData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tempo = "10s"; //1 segundo
    String tempo2 = "30d"; //30 dias

    if(tempo.contains("s")){
        Integer tempoEmSegundos = Integer.parseInt(tempo.replace("s", ""));
        DateTime time = new DateTime();
        DateTime newDate =  time.plusSeconds(tempoEmSegundos);

        Date dataAtualComSegundos = newDate.toDate();
        System.out.println(dataAtualComSegundos);
    }

    if (tempo2.contains("d")){
        Integer tempoEmDias = Integer.parseInt(tempo2.replace("d", ""));
        DateTime time = new DateTime();
        DateTime newDate = time.plusDays(tempoEmDias);

        Date dataAtualComDias = newDate.toDate();
        System.out.println(dataAtualComDias);
    }


}
```

}

Tem que evoluir a lógica e melhorar o código.